# How to fix "AVFoundationErrorDomain - code -11800" on IOS rendering stream videos from s3 aws on react-native-video?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-video

## Bug

I have an app that uses AWS s3 files url to reproduce videos, at first when i installed react-native-video it's not working and showing the error:
"AVFoundationErrorDomain" code -11800
Ive tried a lot of approaches but unsuccessful. There is A LOT of posts relating the same problem, no one could consistently fix it.

### Platform

IOS
Which player are you experiencing the problem on:

- iOS

### Environment info

System:
OS: macOS 11.2
CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
Memory: 538.75 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 14.15.5 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.5 - ~/.yarn/bin/yarn
npm: 6.14.11 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/bin/npm
Watchman: Not Found
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: Not Found
Xcode: 11.3.1/11C505 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 14.0.2 - /Users/caduolivera/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/javac
Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
react-native: 0.63.4 => 0.63.4
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
*react-native*: Not Found

Library version: 5.1.1

### Steps To Reproduce

1. start a fresh rn project
2. Install react-native-video lib
3. try any public url video as source: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4
   ...

### Expected behaviour

1. The video should play or be playable

### Reproducible sample code

```
 <Video
            source={{
              uri: data.arquivo.nm_url,
            }}
            onBuffer={(e) => console.log('buffer video', e)}
            onError={(e) => console.log('err video', e)}
            style={styles.video}
            controls
            paused={true}
          />
```

### Video sample

http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4

----- **EDIT** -----

I have new information about this.
I tried to replace the video component for a webview using react-native-webview, same error, video loads first screen but does not play.
I also tried to open the same video at safari, pasting link url directly... same error.

Conclusion: That makes me think this issue is not related to this lib. But this does not mean we couldnt work together on tests and research to figure it out, in case some of you still have this issue.

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: nop, but since no one was able to help and on a real device this isnt happening so I stopped searching for the solution

Answer (score 0):

For me the "AVFoundationErrorDomain code -11800" went away when i changed the link from http to https.